# Laravel 5 session()->keep method not working

Tags: laravel, session

I have a view with an input date field and a table beneath that. The table is populated based on the date entered. When the date is entered I use a POST method on the form which handles the DB request and returns the same view with the data. I'd like to also return the original date that was entered. I tried `session()->keep` and `flashOnly` methods. None return the input date to the view.
My controller:

```
   public function groupTestAthletes(Request $request)
{        
    $inputDate = null;
    $tests = null;
    if ($request['tgroupdate']){   
        $inputDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request['tgroupdate']);
        $tests = Test::where('test_date', '=', $inputDate->format('Y-m-d'))             
           ->orderBy('athlete_id', 'desc')               
           ->get();            
    }
    $request->session()->keep(['tgroupdate']);        
    //$request->flashOnly(['tgroupdate']);
    return view('npr.test_athletes', ['tests' => $tests]);
```

My view:

```
        <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.search_tgroup') }}"> 
           {{ csrf_field() }}                                              

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tgroupdate" class="control-label">Test Date</label>

            <div class="input-group date" id="testgroupdatepicker">
                <input name="tgroupdate" type="text" style="background-color:#ffffff" readonly="" 
                    value="{{ Session::get('tgroupdate') }}" class="form-control">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>                       
        <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search Athletes
                </button>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token()}}">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to save the date in session. You can save the date in a variable,send it to the view and in the view you can check if variable exist using isset php function.

In Controller

```
 public function groupTestAthletes(Request $request)
{        
    $inputDate = null;
    $tests = null;
    if ($request['tgroupdate']){   
        $inputDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request['tgroupdate']);
        $tests = Test::where('test_date', '=', $inputDate->format('Y- m-d'))             
           ->orderBy('athlete_id', 'desc')               
           ->get();            
    }
    return view('npr.test_athletes', ['tests' => $tests,'selected_date' => $request['tgroupdate']]);
```

And in the view,

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.search_tgroup') }}"> 
           {{ csrf_field() }}                                              

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tgroupdate" class="control-label">Test Date</label>

            <div class="input-group date" id="testgroupdatepicker">
                <input name="tgroupdate" type="text" style="background-color:#ffffff" readonly="" 
                    value="@if(isset($selected_date)) $selected_date @endif" class="form-control">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>                       
        <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search Athletes
                </button>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token()}}">
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Edit:** This minor change in the view gave the optimal solution.
`value="@if(isset($selected_date)){{$selected_date}}@endif"`

Comment: Many thanks. Your `$selected_date` must just be in curly braces. I can now see the old date, but if I click Search Athletes again (without changing the input), I get an error: "Unexpected data found.Trailing data" referencing this line `$inputDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request['tgroupdate']);`
Must I put this in different question rather?

Comment: No need of curly braces around `$selected_date`, '@' opens and closes the php tag. And about the error, `print_r($request['tgroupdate']);die(); `check if you are getting the correct date format.

Comment: If I don't use the curly braces it actually prints the word '$selected_date' in the date field. The `die()` produced the correct format: 12/10/2016

Comment: All sorted now. The carbon error was due to the spaces in the `if` statement. Should be: `value="@if(isset($selected_date)){{$selected_date}}@endif"`
Thanks